# boolean is_ready - pythonic way

Tags: python

I need to check if an object *is ready*. I see two options:

```
class Foo:
  def is_ready(self):
    # ...
    return result_of_some_calculations

# usage
foo.is_ready()
```

or

```
class Foo:
  @property
  def is_ready(self):
    return result_of_some_calculations

# usage
foo.is_ready
```

Is there any pythonic preference for one convention or the other?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `self` reference in the method? e.g.`def is_ready(self)`

Comment: Personally, the second form looks more proper to me. The name of the method implies you are querying a property of the object. It reads very naturally, and in my opinion fits better with the zen of python.

Comment: @elParaguayo: of course I do :)

Comment: How heavyweight is the `is_ready` method? Is it something like `self.fuel >= self.flight.fuel_required + safety_margin`, or is it something like `self.query_coordination_server_in_china('ready?')`?

Comment: @JakubM. Nice. For what it's worth, I also prefer the second form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using decorators is more pythonic than normal function calls

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? Not every argumentless method should be a property.

Comment: @user2357112: I said it is more pythonic to use decorators. Not talking of cases with/without arguments

Comment: I'm still not sure why you keep referring to decorators, too. The decorator is incidental; the property is the important part. Properties actually predate decorators.